# jQuery function script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to put values into other textareas after submitting a form.

HTML:

```
 <form id="productionForm" name="productionForm" method="POST">
     <input type="text" id='ime_2'/>
     <textarea id='text_2'></textarea>
     <input type='submit' onclick="send_reply('2','2');" id='test'/>
</form>

<div id="reply_error_2"></div>

<input id="cid"/>
<input id="cuid"/>
```

JavaScript:

```
function send_reply(id,id2) {
    var chk = true;
    if ($("#ime_"+id).val().length == 0) {
        $("#reply_error_"+id).html("Polje Ime nije popunjeno.").show(); 
        chk = false; 
    }
    var reply_text = $("#text_"+id).val();
    if (reply_text.length == 0) { 
        $("#reply_error_"+id).html("Polje za odgovor nije popunjeno.").show(); 
        chk = false; 
    }
    if (reply_text.length > 1500) { 
        $("#reply_error_"+id).html("Odgovor ima više od 1500 karaktera.").show(); 
        chk = false; 
    }
    if (chk) {
        $("#cid").val(id);
        $("#cuid").val(id2);
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6fb27Lad/

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: send_reply is not defined(index):55 onclick

Comment: @Vladimir: That error tells you that `send_reply` isn't global; the functions you use in `onXyz` attributes must be *global* functions. That's one of the many reasons not to use `onXyz` attributes. Given the code above, you can readily hook it up like this: `$("#test").click(function() { send_reply('2', '2') });`

Comment: In the code you've copied you're missing a final closing }

Comment: I update Jsfiddle in main post plz help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accoding to fiddle you provided

First select `no wrap -in <head>` from sidebar in a fiddle.Because the functions you define are defined in an onload function

`<a type='submit' onclick="send_reply('2','2');return flase;"
 id='test'>TRY </a>`

Second spelling of false above is wrong.

Third add `}` at last of js you dint close the function

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/singhakash07/8p4ywv9h/)

Answer (score 1):

When you click a `type="submit"` button in a form, the form data is posted to the server, and the server replies with a new page; the current page is torn down and replaced with the new page's content.

If you don't want that to happen (for instance, if you're sending the data to the server using ajax or some such, or just using the information purely client-side), use `type="button"` instead.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're attempting some validation based on the field length. If you want the form not to submit then that function needs to return false. It looks like the chk variable is set up to do this but not being used. I've added "return chk" to the bottom of your script and it looks to me like the snippet is working.

```js
function send_reply(id, id2) {
    var chk = true;
    if ($("#ime_" + id).val().length == 0) {
      $("#reply_error_" + id).html("Polje Ime nije popunjeno.").show();
      chk = false;
    }
    var reply_text = $("#text_" + id).val();
    if (reply_text.length == 0) {
      $("#reply_error_" + id).html("Polje za odgovor nije popunjeno.").show();
      chk = false;
    }
    if (reply_text.length > 1500) {
      $("#reply_error_" + id).html("Odgovor ima više od 1500 karaktera.").show();
      chk = false;
    }
    if (chk) {
      $("#cid").val(id);
      $("#cuid").val(id2);

    }
  return chk
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="productionForm" name="productionForm" method="POST">
  <input type="text" id='ime_2' />
  <textarea id='text_2'></textarea>
  <input type='submit' onclick="send_reply('2','2');" id='test' />
</form>

<div id="reply_error_2"></div>

<input id="cid" />
<input id="cuid" />
```

Comment: Yes it should do some validations, I think problem is with http://jsfiddle.net/6fb27Lad/  for some reason not working there.. :/

Comment: add "return chk; }" to the end of your code

Comment: Also cid and cuid should take value from <input type="text" id='ime_2' />
  <textarea id='text_2'></textarea>:  not value from function....

Comment: I tried but just back blank page....